# Artisan output not working for route:cache

Tags: laravel

Why doesn't this code show any output result?

```
$exitCode = \Artisan::call('route:cache');
$artisanOutput = \Artisan::output();
dd($artisanOutput);
```

Another artisan console code example shows a result, but this one does not work.

Comment: can you try firing `route:list` and see if you get the result or not.

Comment: @Webinion i want show success message.  also `return redirect` not work after call this artisan.

Comment: `return redirect()->action('AdminController@adminSettings')->with('success', $successMessage);`  it not work

Comment: @dev4xy So, the idea is to fix redirect problem?

Comment: @Gabriel both.But redirects are more important. i think laravel must be reload after call this artisan.

Comment: Reword for clarity

Answer (score 0):

if your  app environment is production then you should run

```
$exitCode = \Artisan::call('route:cache',['--force'=> true]);
$artisanOutput = \Artisan::output();
dd($artisanOutput);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no no. my project is debug mode. you try this code. you see this not work!

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment i read. Redirect is what you are trying to achieve.

why not use this instead?

```
return redirect('adminSettings')->with('success', $successMessage);
```

And your route should look like this:

```
Route::get('adminSettings', 'AdminController@adminSettings');
```

Looking at your original question

```
$exitCode = \Artisan::call('route:cache');
$artisanOutput = \Artisan::output();
dd($artisanOutput);
```

Can you try 'php artisan route:cache' from your terminal? What is the output? I am using 5.6 and the output gives me some error. So i think that's the issue.